VScode extension error EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'c:\Users\Kashaf\.vscode\extensions
I am uable to install the extensions in VScode and the error is shown in image. Please help
Error below >>
EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'c:\Users\Kashaf.vscode\extensions.ab7c373b-a311-4d78-9ab8-d945e0f0d3ba',EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\Kashaf\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs.5c9075ca-0f8c-4e13-8250-fb9a2e25577b' -> 'c:\Users\Kashaf\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs\dart-code.dart-code-3.86.0'
I want to install VSCode extensions but it is giving me error.

Perhaps it wants you to CachedExtensionVSIXs.5c9075ca-0f8c-4e13-8250-fb9a2e25577b rename that to dart-code.dart-code-3.86.0? Have you checked what the file is actually called in the filesystem?
